# How to set new window property using Cypress

Tags: window, cypress

I would like to set a new window property upon page load in Cypress. For example, this is a new property that I would like to set in my application context after page finished loading.

```
window.configTemplate = {
   templates: {}
}
```

I've tried using the following methods but when I tried to access the window property in the console, "window.configTemplate" returned "undefined"

```
cy.window().then(win => {

win.configTemplate = {
         templates: {
            'list-1': {
              index: 1,
              componentRef: 'titleContainer',
              props: {
                title: 'Test XX',
              },
            }
         }
}
});
```

I've tried putting the snippet of code within  onBeforeLoad (win) {} as well but it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that is does work, but you are logging the wrong window (Cypress runner has `window` and you access the app window with

```
cy.window().then(win => {
  console.log(win.configTemplate)
```

But does your app need `configTemplate`? Or just the tests? If tests, you can use the runner window, or the `Cypress` object

```
Cypress.configTemplate = {
  templates: {
    ...
  }

console.log(Cypress.configTemplate)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [before load event](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/catalog-of-events) on Cypress?

```
Cypress.on('window:before:load', win => {
  win.configTemplate = {
    "templates": {
        "list-1": {
            "index": 1,
            "componentRef": "titleContainer",
            "props": {
                "title": "Test XX"
            }
        }
    }
  }
});
```

This will set the `windows.configTemplate` before page load. You could also adjust the event to meet your requirements.